# html send array inside form onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, validation

I'm wondering if it's possible to send array of values for javascript function via onsubmit inside the form.
Let's say I have five inputs in form, and in the form I have:

```
onsubmit="return checkvalues(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5)"
```

So the checkvalues() function can validate the inputed values.
But I'm wondering how not to send 5 values but one array, so something like:

```
onsubmit="return checkvalues(array(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5))"
```

is it possible so the Javascript function will recognize "someArray" as array?:

```
function checkvalues(array someArray) {
    somehow_loop_through_array someArray
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit the values in an array and define the function such that it accepts one parameter. You don't have to specify that this parameter should be an array in the function definition in JavaScript, just deal with the parameter as an array inside the function.

```
onsubmit="return checkvalues([value1, value2, value3, value4, value5])"

function checkvalues(someArray) {
  for(var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    // do something with the array elements
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the given param is an array and loop through it:

```js
function checkvalues(someArray) {
  // check if someArray is an array (if its for sure an array you can skip this part of course)
  if(someArray.isArray()){
    // loop array ES5 way
    someArray.forEach(function (item, index) {
      // do the check for each item here
    });
    
    //loop array old way
    for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
      // do the check for each item here with someArray[i]
    }
  }
}
```

I've added two possible ways. `forEach` is the "cleaner" version, but won't work on older browsers. So if you have to support old browsers, you have to use the second option

Answer (score 0):

you can send the values like this

```
onsubmit="return checkvalues(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5)"
```

and you will be able to receive the values in a function using spread operator

```
function checkvalues(...values){
  console.log(values.length);
}
```

**OR**
you can receive in the below manner also

```
function checkvalues(v1,v2,v3,v4){
  console.log(arguments[0]);
}
```